# Erro na mensagem da View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho esse código:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/InternalAuditRecord/SaveInternalAuditRecord",
                type: "post",
                data: $("form#internalAuditRecordRegisterForm").serialize()+"&idResponsibles="+responsibles+"&idAuditors="+auditors,
                success: function (res) {
                    if (typeof (res) == "object") {
                        if (res.success) {
                            window.location.replace("/InternalAuditRecord/InternalAuditRecord");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(res);
                            //flashMessage();
                            if ($("#Name").val() == "") {
                                $("#Name").addClass(validationClassErrosType.input)
                            }
                            validationCheckImage($("#Name"), $("#Name").parent());

                            var text = String(res).split(",");
                            var errorMessages = ["<ul>"];
                            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                                errorMessages.push("<li>"+text[i]+"<li>");
                            }
                            errorMessages.push("</ul>");

                            $(".validation-summary-errors").html(errorMessages.join(""));
                            loadSwitches();
                        }
                    }
```

Meu controller:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid){              
   ModelState.OrderByKeys(criticalAnalysisRecord.GetValidationOrder());
   Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
   return Json(ModelState.GetModelStateErros());
}
```

E a View:

```
<div id="messages">
  <div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Que coloca a mensagem na View porem esta indo uma tag li a mais, como pode ser observado na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Qual o resultado se você colocar um "console.log("Erro :"+text[i]);" dentro do for, antes de dar um push no erro ?

Comment: Erro :O campo "Descrição" deve ser preenchido

Comment: Conseguir tirar, obrigado eu dei um for para tira o elementos que estão com texto vazio.

Comment: Que bom que consegui, mas seria interessante ver o porque de estar vindo mensagens em branco quando não deveria. Se não podes criar alguns problemas com esses códigos desnecessários para arrumar esses bugs.

Comment: Acho que não consigo reproduzir já que só nesse que estava dando esse erro por enquanto